# Rope twisted around other straight rope. What is length of remaining mid rope?

Tags: geometry

If two ropes smooth are of sufficient length, of equal
dia. The one is twisted wraped around the mid straight rope so that the surface of mid wire/rope is completely covered. What is the length of the uncovered mid wire?
*What is the length reduction if both wires are twisted around each other in straight line?

Comment: What happens to the length of the rope when you bend it? Different kinds of rope behave differently. Also, how are you measuring the length of a bent rope?

Comment: @apt1002 it goes into torus but with a slant.